# eslint error 'value of props' is missing in props validation using React JS on moving the props from return section to a new function

Tags: reactjs, react-proptypes

I'm getting below eslint error after moving the props to a separate function.

Here is my initial code and it is getting compiled successfully:

```
const MessageComponent = (props) => {
const { intl } = props;
const { formatMessage, messages } = intl;

return (
    <div>
        {formatMessage(messages.some_message)}
    </div>
);
```

After getting the message from a new function:

```
const MessageComponent = (props) => {
const { intl } = props;
const { formatMessage, messages } = intl;

const getMessage = () => (
    <div>
        {formatMessage(messages.some_message)}
    </div>
);

return (
    getMessage()
);
```

then getting the error:

```
  219:63  error  'intl.messages.some_message' is missing in props validation
react/prop-types
```

For both cases I haven't defined default props, so what is the difference? why is it complaining?

thanks in advance!